# Six months probationary period

Tags: employment, employer, unemployment, philippines

I have read and understand 6 months probationary period rule, that employee exceeds 6 months of probationary period shall be regularized otherwise informed by the employer to not continue. Now the question is employee is informed ahead that he/she will be regularized, however wished to decline because he/she doesn't agree with the new contract/rules. Now,  does the employee has the right to do so?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the employee can choose not to accept the contract offered at the end of the probationary period and thereby allow the probationary period to end without accepting a long-term position.

This is usually called "quitting".